# Should we edit out potentially inappropriate content if they might be an important part of a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Port 25 not open, how send email?](https://superuser.com/questions/1466626/port-25-not-open-how-send-email)

That question *might* be legitimate, but with part of the email domain contains an inappropriate word, I'm not sure whether editing that out harms the question or not.

The problem explained might be generic enough that it can be replaced with a generic domain "@mycompany.com", but the problem might be specific on *that* domain that editing out even a part of it will change the question drastically.

As of now, I've edited out part of it. Now, **what is the proper approach to this question?**

<sup>I sense spam or troll post, but let's ignore that</sup>

Comment: The two words that make up that domain are legitimate English words.  **Only when used to reference a body part is one of those words inappropriate.**  You raise the real question, if the question is legitimate or not, which I suspect is indeed not legitimate.

Comment: I suspect Dr. Dickhopper would be quite offended by your observation.  :-)

Comment: Perspective is everything... "Dick" is a common nickname for Richard, such as Richard "Dick" Nixon (aka Tricky Dicky).  Similarly, "bitch" is still utilized to refer to female dogs; "pussy" is still utilized as a name for cats, as well as by at least two bands, Pussy Riot and The Pussycat Dolls; etc.  There are definitely inappropriate words that should be edited out, but before doing so we should ask ourselves whether the word could be being utilized appropriately.

Comment: Whatever you do, mycompany.com is not appropriate. I spend enough of my time editing that kind of domain out and replacing them with RFC 2606 domains.

Comment: example.com is a much better choice than mycompany.com; it's explicitly reserved for such purposes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tbh, in this case I don't think the domain is *particularly* critical to a more general answer.

Practically - the question involves

1. Having an MX record. Any domain can have an MX record.
2. The appropriate port not being open, which is critical and useful, and not domain dependent.
3. That's a spam site.... This got more fun.

I've changed the link to example.com for now. Its not ideal but looking at the totality of the situation, I don't think anyone would mind. Considering changing the domain doesn't particularly break anything - and OP seems technically competent enough to run dig and portscans, I don't see any issues in editing here.